# Express not running in El Capitan OSX

Tags: node.js, express, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I've updated my Macbook Pro to El Capitan OSX version, and now when I try to run an express app that I'd created in Yosemite using

```
$node app.js
```

The app doesn't run.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Even a new express applications have the same issue.

Comment: Does anything happen?

Comment: Nothing. Just like I would type an enter in the terminal window.

Comment: express works just fine for me...try installing again and update node and npm @DevArtisan

Comment: What is the output for  "which node" and "node --version".

Comment: Thanks for your answers. My version is $ node --version
v4.2.1

Comment: FWIW I have no problems running node 4.2.1 and Express 4.x under El Capitan.